# Firebase Functions - generate and host static webpage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions to generate an HTML file and now I'd like to host it together with related assets (js, css, fonts etc.) but without success.

I call the function, it generates the file properly and puts it in Firebase Storage together with js/css/other assets. Now I would like to return a URL of the index.html file so that the user can access it in the browser and the .html page will have access to the assets. Unfortunately the generated URL enforces download but I'm pretty sure that even if I managed it somehow, it won't be able to access asset files.

I know it's possible on AWS (S3 bucket) but can I do it on Firebase? Firebase Hosting doesn't seem to be the right solution in that case, does it?

Comment: you can configure rewrites in `firebase.json` and handle the requests with `expressjs` middle-ware... there's no need to save the `HTML` anywhere, just send it to the browser, which requests it.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to serve static web content directly from a Cloud Storage bucket?

Comment: @MartinZeitler the thing is that I have an entire bundle meaning HTML with local assets (css, js, fonts etc.). It'll be quite difficult to create an endpoint in express for each file.

Comment: @DougStevenson That would be ideal but from what I know, unlike in S3, files don't have access to other in the same bucket

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website

Answer (score 2):

Don't save it to Storage, that's a bad use case for this scenario. Instead, save it to Hosting:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Also, you can consider serving the content directly from the cloud function, probably there's no need to create a static version first.

Comment: If it is a content that will never change, by hosting a static version of it you will save money on Firestore queries for instance. It will preventing the users from making heavy queries to the database.

Comment: You could also enable cache if the content is only changed periodically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache

Comment: see also: "When a process generates static content programmatically (for example, user-generated content such as a wiki or a news article), you can deploy the generated content as static files rather than serving them dynamically. This saves you expensive compute power and serves your files in a more scalable way."
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy